# Finding the baseline shifting points for noisy data

Tags: r, signal-processing, boxplot, noise, anomaly-detection

I have a raw signal which is attached in this question . The x-axis is time, and the y-axis is the signal response. As you can see from the noisy data, the baseline of the noisy signal, B1, appears to start shifting from t1 s to a new baseline value, B2, at approximately t2 s ([Raw signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAeWd.png)). I am using R to do the analysis. What I did was group the data every 0.5s and plot the box-plots for that group as shown in the figure ([Boxplots of data every 0.5 s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmXQI.png)). This approach is helpful, but changes slightly depending on time interval you define for the boxplots and also the noise in the signal . Is there any other mathematical/ statistical approach to figure out when exactly this baseline shift takes place and at what time the final baseline value is reached?. Since there are hundreds of such probes, I would like the program to automatically find t1 and t2 ,than the user looking at the graph manually.

Comment: This sounds too broad for SO. Maybe the question would find a better fit on [crossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it appears to be closer to a statistical methodology question. If you post it there, delete your question here and consider adding a bit more detail about your model and data.

Comment: Based on the info you've given, your baseline seems completely subjective. You could make it the mean of your total signal, the time to T1, the time to T2, or something that makes sense to you. If there is no baseline period of measurement, then it seems impossible to answer your question.